# Identifying usernames having duplicate user-id in /etc/passwd file

Tags: awk

I am trying to find out all users in my /etc/passwd which has a user-id of 0. It should display the username as well as the user-id.  I tried the following:

```
awk -F: '{
count[$3]++;}END {
for (i in count)
   print i, count[i];
 }'  passwd
```

It gives the duplicate user-ids and how many times they are occuring . I actually want the usernames also along with the duplicate user-ids  similar like

```
zama      0
root      0
bin       100
nologin   100
```

Will be great if the solution is provided with awk asscociative arrays. Other methods are also fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
awk -F: '{
count[$3]++; names[$3 "," count[$3]] = $1}END {
for (i in count) {
  for (j = 1; j <= count[i]; j++) {
   print names[i "," j], i, count[i];
  }
}
 }'  passwd
```

Comment: Thanks for replying . I tried the above example earlier , it is giving the usernames , but I want all the usernames having duplicated user-ids in column 3 . It is now only displaying unique user-names corresponding to user-id 3 .

Comment: to get *all* usernames, concatenate encountered values, like this:
  `names[$3] = names[$3] "\t" $1`

Comment: I updated the solution to allow you to iterate through all the different names with the same uid. Sorry I just posted it now, but I lost internet last night just as I was posting -- so frustrating :)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
awk -F: '$3~/0/{if($3 in a){d[$3];a[$3]=a[$3]"\n"$3" "$1}else{a[$3]=$3" "$1}};END{for(x in d)print a[x]}' /etc/passwd
```

or this non-awk solution:

```
cut -d: -f1,3 /etc/passwd |
sort -st: -k2,2n |
tr ':' ' ' |
uniq -Df1 | 
sed 's/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\2 \1/p;d'
```

Comment: Hi Potong , the non-awk solution looks great . But can you please explain the sed statement how it is working . It is somewhat complex for me . And , sorry for coming back late here

Comment: Ooops! I left some debugging commands in. I've removed it now. Basically all the sed statement does is reverse the first two (actually only two) fields so that the used-id comes before the username.

Answer (score -1):

```
myid=`cat passwd|awk -F: '{print $3 }'| sort | uniq -d`
for i in `echo "$myid"`;do
    egrep  "^.*:x:$i" passwd | awk -F: '{print $1 , $3}'
done
```

Comment: That's one handsome Useless Use of `echo` in Backticks. http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#backticks